# Java activity calling a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

First le me start by stating I am fairly new to Java and Android Studio, so please bear with me. my background has been in Visual Basic going way back.

I have an activity that tries to verify that what was entered is a valid Item Number by UPC entered. When only one match all is good. My problem starts when the UPC entered brings back more than one matching item. What I am attempting to do (First time using fragments) is Replace part of the screen with a recycler view showing the matching items and descriptions.

When comes backs with multiple items I call an event called setupMulitpleItems with the following code:

```
public void setupMultiItems(String mScan){
Timber.d("Multiple matching Items");

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("valuesArray",mScan);
SelectItemFragment fragobj = new SelectItemFragment();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction  = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.include2,  fragobj);


fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Not sure how many parts of this code will actually work but I am getting underline on the replace line.

```
     "'replace(int, android.app.Fragment)' in 'android.app.FragmentTransaction' cannot be applied to '(int, com.procatdt.stockright.activities.SelectItemFragment)'" 
meesage.
```

I am using the following imports for Fragments.

```
 import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
 import android.app.Fragment;
 import android.app.FragmentManager;
```

Figured I would also include the XML for the activity that is currently running when I want to use Fragment.

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackgroundGray"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_select_item"
    tools:context="com.procatdt.stockright.activities.PutAwayAreaActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"

       >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/include2"
            layout="@layout/frm1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="left" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/include"
            layout="@layout/layout_numpad5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="220dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
           />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am trying to replace include2 with Fragment.
Hope this enough info but if anyone needs to see more let me know and I ill attach code.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to pass the object of your fragment to `replace` method, there is no need to pass the class declaration and type of class

so just remove

```
// this is enough
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.include2,  fragobj);

// remove this
//fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.include2,android.app.Fragment  SelectItemFragment);
```

Comment: Sorry I left that in. Even with that line still getting same message.

Comment: you need to use the id of `Framelayout`  instead of `R.id.include2,` include tag

Comment: pavneet, I see what you are saying but I have tried several different ways now and no luck. Can you see what that line should read?

Comment: do you have any fragmelayou in your `frm1` layout , if yes then use the id of framelayout tag instead of include tag, if still an issue then post the xml code  and complete error details

Comment: complaining about fragobj with error of         'replace(int, android.app.Fragment)' in 'android.app.FragmentTransaction' cannot be applied to '(int, com.procatdt.stockright.activities.SelectItemFragment)'  SelectItemFragment is the name of the Fragment Activity. I made the fragment an activity.

Comment: `SelectItemFragment` has to be a fragment instead of an activity like `SelectItemFragment extends Fragment`, activities can only be started uing intent

Comment: Correct. When I created it I used new Fragment. So it does have the extends Fragment so it does have the line  public class SelectItemFragment extends Fragment. It has its own layout with a recycler name lrecycler that I want to have show when multiple items are returned. the lrecycler should replace the layout for include2 which is an include on activity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169605/discussion-between-pavneet-singh-and-tom).